# Delete from a SQL Table based on another table

Tags: sql, select, subquery, exists

I have 2 SQL tables: **TableA** and **TableB**. Both these tables have the same exact columns and types. TableA contains more data. TableB contains the data that I want to delete in TableA. Before actually deleting data, I want to select the data from TableA first to verify that the count matches TableB. How would I do a SELECT statement for this type of query? One thing that makes this a little trickier is that the tables do not contain a primary key. A lot of questions I saw related to this one involved using some sort of id in the query. That's not an option in my case. Once I know this, I should be able to form my deletion query. The columns are name, age, and gender. Again, none of these columns are a primary key.

When I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA
```

I get a count of **100,000**

When I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB
```

I get a count of **10,000**

I know this query is wrong, but when I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB)
```

I get a count of **100,000**. How can I select the data from TableA, so that it matches the data in TableB?

Comment: Consider using Inner Join could be helpful

Comment: If you expect someone here to provide you with a query, you will need to describe which column(s) relate the two tables.

Comment: Just edited to include column names.

Comment: Why is count for TableB wrong? If there are 100,000 records, count should be 100,000.

Comment: If all 3 fields together define a unique record, then that is a compound key. Join on all 3 fields. Use compound key as ID for deletion.

Comment: Would something like this work? SELECT A.name, A.age, A.gender FROM TableA AS A
LEFT JOIN TableB AS B
ON A.name = B.name
AND A.age = B.agen
AND A.gender = B.gender

Comment: @June7 The count for TableB is correct, I was referring to the 3rd query above. I was expecting the 3rd query to return a count of 10,000 but it was 100,000

Comment: That EXISTS query makes no sense to me. Build a compound INNER JOIN with all 3 fields and see how many records are returned.

Comment: Please explain what "matching" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query below 10,000 returns the common records of the two tables. And you can use it.

```
SELECT t1.name,t1.age,t1.gender
FROM TableA t1
LEFT JOIN TableB t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.age = t2.age AND t1.gender = t2.gender
```